# MYSQL COUNT return duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to use `COUNT` and return with a `COUNT` column for each row. If i were to use `GROUP BY` it would only return 1 row for each value. I **want** it to show duplicates.

Example Data:
**City**
Seattle
Dallas
Seattle
New York
Boston
Boston
Portland

**I would like to return:**
Seattle 2 
Dallas  1
Seattle 2
New York    1
Boston  2
Boston  2
Portland    1

Answer (score 3):

you can use `correlated subquery`.

```
SELECT  a.City,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName b WHERE a.City = b.City) totalCount
FROM    tableName a
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c84ad5/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can join the original table with a subquery that uses `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t1.city, citycount
FROM myTable t1
JOIN (SELECT city, COUNT(city) citycount
      FROM myTable
      GROUP BY city) t2
USING (city)
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c84ad5/4)

Comment: @fthiella Thanks. Maybe because I didn't add a sqlfiddle like 491243 did. Fixed that.

Comment: @491243 Maybe because we forgot to tell the OP not to use the mysql_ extensions, even though there's no PHP in the question? :)